# How to implement physical effect, perspective effect on Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, game-physics

I'm researching about 2D game for Android to implement an Android Game Project. My project looks nearly like [PaperToss](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bfs.papertoss). Instance of throwing a page, my game will throw a coin. Suppose that I have a coin put in three-dimensional that have coordinates at A(x,y,z). I throw that point ahead, after 1/100 second, that coin move from A(x,y,z) to A'(x',y',z'). By this way, I  have two problems need to solve.

1. Determine the formulas can be used to compute the coordinates of the coin at time t.
   This problem is under-researching. I have no idea to solve this problem.
2. Mapping three-dimensional points to a two-dimensional and use those new coordinates (a two-dimensional coordinates) to draw our coin on screen. I have found two solutions for this problem: [Orthographic projection & Perspective projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection)

However, my old friend said that OpenGL supports to solve problems like my problems. Any body have experiences about my problems?

Help me please :)

Thank for reading my question.

Comment: This actually sounds more like a 3D game...Are you planning to have 3D model of a coin or just a coin animated by a series images?

Comment: Can i implement this project with 2D technology? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

My personal opinion is to use a 3D engine since I don't like doing hacky stuff trying to fake 3D with 2D. However, 2D is much more beginner friendly, so if you're not planning to do anything fancy like actually emulating how coin actually rotates in air then I think it's doable in 2D.

My approach to do this would be to use a framework like [libgdx](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/) instead of dealing with OpenGL ES directly. They have built in support for view projection ([PerspectiveCamera](http://libgdx.l33tlabs.org/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/PerspectiveCamera.html)), high level 2D/3D rendering support and even a wrapper for OpenGL ES if you really want to go low level. I'm not so sure about how you would approach the physics part right now.

Good luck....